# xforms HTTP 404 on textarea.min.js.map and orbeon-form-runner-opt.js.map

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Orbeon 2017.2.2. After loading this version I get the following errors from all my xhtml pages:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (Textarea.min.js.map, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (orbeon-form-runner-opt.js.map, line 0)

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.map` files are only loaded when you have your web browser's dev tools open, as they are used for debugging JavaScript. The browser will not attempt to load them otherwise. So no, you should not be worried.

Comment: I actually see the errors when I open the browser inspector so presumably they should have been loaded at that point? Anyway: I’ll not be worried